# Mailchimp conditional merge tags

Tags: if-statement, tags, mailchimp

I'm new with email marketing and I would really appreciate if someone could help me to show what i'm missing in conditional 
merge tag blocks. I've made numerous attempts in building the template with *|IF:|* *|END:IF|* formula, based on the specific fields in my contacts lists, but nothing worked.
My colleague who is on the same knowledge level insists that this option is available for paid users which I'm not and says that I need to choose a paid plan in order to
proceed with this. Is this correct? Or I just need to have a better look at the formula?

Comment: I updated this with an answer and a link to detailed conditional statement from MailChimp.

Answer (score 1):

I would say its more about you looking at your logic. Here is the URL from MC's site showing what you can do with their conditional statements:

```
IF
*|IF:MERGE|*
content to display
*|END:IF|*


ELSE

*|IF:MERGE|*
content to display
*|ELSE:|*
alternative content to display
*|END:IF|*


ELSEIF

*|IF:TRANSACTIONS >= 20|*
Enjoy this 40% off coupon! *|COUPON40|*
*|ELSEIF:TRANSACTIONS >= 10|*
Enjoy this 20% off coupon! *|COUPON20|*
*|ELSE:|*
Enjoy this 10% off coupon! *|COUPON10|*
*|END:IF|*

IFNOT

*|IFNOT:MERGE|*
content to display
*|
```

Full list of conditional statements can be found here: [MailChimp Conditional Formating](http://kb.mailchimp.com/merge-tags/use-conditional-merge-tag-blocks)

Cheers

Comment: FYI, the `ELSEIF` Mailchimp tag does not work as expected. You must use nested `IF` to achieve a comparable effect. Maybe this is because they now offer "conditional blocks" as a new product.

Comment: Also, FYI, using conditional merge tags, while documented, and while responsible for significant to your company, and while it is an advertised product feature that you are paying for, are not officially supported by the company. You will learn this the first time you contact customer support about something not working.

Comment: @WilliamEntriken, This is what i found at the mail chimp site unforrtunatly. You can add that as an answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @William Entriken for pointing out the ELSEIF tags no longer work.

Here's an implementation with nested ifs. The following assumes a week starts with Monday as DAY_ID = 1 and ends with Sunday = 7

```
*|IF:DAY_ID < 2|*
Monday
*|ELSE:|*
*|IF:DAY_ID < 3|*
Tuesday
*|ELSE:|*
*|IF:DAY_ID < 4|*
Wednesday
*|ELSE:|*
*|IF:DAY_ID < 5|*
Thursday
*|ELSE:|*
*|IF:DAY_ID < 6|*
Friday
*|ELSE:|*
Weekend
*|END:IF|*
*|END:IF|*
*|END:IF|*
*|END:IF|*
*|END:IF|*
```